# Focus on input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Template is 'tabs' with 2 tabs. On the first tab, I have an `input` field I want to put focus on. It is working when the app starts with the `input` field being focused, but when I switch to the second tab and then back to the first tab, the input loses focus.

I would like it be focused when I go from tab 2 to 1 too. When I click outside the element, it to loses focus as well. I actually want that `input` field to be ALWAYS focused.

I tried some already mentioned solutions:

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: { trigger: '=focusMe' },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
        if(value === true) { 
          //console.log('trigger',value);
          //$timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus();
            scope.trigger = true;
          //});
        }
      });
    }
  };
});


<label class="item item-input" focus-me>  
  <input type="number" class="somett" ng-model="code" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 100 }" placeholder="Ready" ng-change="load(code) " focus-on="focusTextInput"  autofocus>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [View LifeCycle and Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/).

Add this to your controller.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
  $scope.$broadcast("focusTextInput");
});
```